# Retrieve identity inside a ILogger custom implementation

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am implementing a custom Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger (and ILoggerProvider. I would like to retrieve the current identity but I really don't how since I cannot inject anything, and I also don't know the current HttpContext.

My approach may be wrong... Is there a typical solution for this kind of requirement?

here are some few lines of code:

```
factory.AddProvider(new MongoDBLoggerProvider(connectionString, database));
```

in the provider:

```
public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
{
    var client = new MongoClient(_connectionString);
    var database = client.GetDatabase(_database);

    return new MongoDBLogger(database, categoryName);
}
```

In the logger:

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var entry = new LogEntry
    {
        Date = now,
        UserId = ?????
        Exception = exception,
        Level = logLevel,
        State = state.ToString(),
        Scope = _categoryName,
        EventId = eventId.Id,
        EventName = eventId.Name,
        FormattedState = formatter != null ? formatter(state, exception) : null
    };

    PushAndForget(entry, _database);
}
```

Comment: Are you declaring this logger class within the same project boundaries as is yours asp.net context?

Comment: Thanks for your intereset. For custom logs, I am typically injecting IloggerFactory in my viewmodels (which are also injected into the controllers). Does it answers?

Comment: Please use the correct tags, when asking a question. ASP.NET5 isn't used and monitored much. The correct name and tag is [tag:asp.net-core]. Also use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] instead of [tag:asp.net-mvc] for ASP.NET Core MVC. Otherwise people won't find and read your questions

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a working custom logger that can access identities. It should accomplish what you are looking for, I have just renamed some of the classes for readability purposes in my example. This microsoft article may also be a helpful resource for you as you design your customer logger https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-a-custom-logger

You can set up configuration values if you please:

```
public class LoggingServiceConfig
{
    public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; } = LogLevel.Information;
    public int EventId { get; set; } = 0;
    public ConsoleColor Color { get; set; } = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
}
```

Config class has the following usings:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Set up a custom logger:

```
public class LoggingService : ILogger
{
    private readonly ILogStore _logStore;
    private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly LoggingServiceConfig _config;

    public LoggingService(string categoryName, LoggingServiceConfig config,
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        ILogStore logStore)
    {
        _config = config;
        _logStore = logStore;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    }

    public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return true; //currently log everything regardless of logLevel
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        LogEntry log = new LogEntry(); //this is your log entry
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
        {
            var userManager = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager<AspNetUser>>(); //this is the user manager you can use to perform identity functions, you can likewise request the signInManager  service as well if needed

            var user = userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);

            if (user != null && user.Result != null)
            {
                //do something with user.Result as this is your identity user record
                log.UserId = user.Result.UserId;
                log.Username = user.Result.UserName;
            }
        }
        
        if (exception != null)
        {
            log.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
        }

        var signInManager = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<SignInManager<AspNetUser>>(); //I accessed the sign in manager in case you need it to conditionally affect how you write create your LogEntry

        //add other properties you want to the log here
        _logStore.Add(log); //this is where you can call your PushAndForget or any method to write to database assumed you injected it correctly or the like, you can reference the .net core respository pattern for further details on how i did my _logStore
    }
}
```

Custom logger has the following usings:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

Set up a logging provider:

```
public class LoggingServiceLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    private readonly LoggingServiceConfig _config;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, LoggingService> _loggers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, LoggingService>();
    private readonly ILogStore _logStore;
    private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public LoggingServiceLoggerProvider(LoggingServiceConfig config,
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        ILogStore logStore)
    {
        _config = config;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _logStore = logStore; //this is a repository for storing logs
    }
    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        return _loggers.GetOrAdd(categoryName, name => new LoggingService(name, _config,
            _httpContextAccessor,
            _logStore));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _loggers.Clear();
    }
}
```

Custom logging provider has the following using statements:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

In your Startup.cs make sure the configure method has a ILoggerFactory loggerFactory parameter and include the following:

```
loggerFactory.AddProvider(new LoggingServiceLoggerProvider(
                                  new LoggingServiceConfig
                                  {
                                      LogLevel = LogLevel.Error,
                                      Color = ConsoleColor.Red
                                  },
                                  new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor(),
                                  new LogStore()));
```